# React : Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on ReactJS Search filter , Currently I am facing a problem when I enter match input application is crashed and give this error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, companyName, account, venueCode, openDate, website, primaryPhone, emailAddress, description, firstName, lastName, active, title, department, officePhone, mobilePhone, tenantId, hidden, deleted, parentId}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` Somebody please help me how to solve this problem . I am beginner and don't have much knowledge to resolve this problem . First time application is rendering successfully when I enter some match input it give me an error .

**Code**

```
        class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when you try to render an object instead of JSX. Making my best educated guess, I think this line is the problem:

```
let filtered=this.state.data.filter((item)=>{
      return item.companyName.indexOf(keyword) > -1
    });
```

Filtered appears to be an array of objects, not JSX, so then in the render method:

```
{this.state.filtered.length === 0 ? dataRender : this.state.filtered}
```

potentially tries to render filtered objects, not JSX.

To fix this, try adding this:

```
const filterRender=this.state.filtered.map((dataItem)=>(
  <Table.Row key={dataItem.id}>
  <Table.Cell>{dataItem.companyName}</Table.Cell>
  <Table.Cell>{dataItem.primaryPhone}</Table.Cell>
  <Table.Cell>{dataItem.emailAddress}</Table.Cell>
  <Table.Cell>{dataItem.venueCode}</Table.Cell>
  <Table.Cell>{dataItem.account}</Table.Cell>
  <Table.Cell>{dataItem.openDate}</Table.Cell>
  <Table.Cell>{dataItem.website}</Table.Cell>
  <Table.Cell>{dataItem.description}</Table.Cell>
</Table.Row>
))
```

and changing this to:

```
{this.state.filtered.length === 0 ? dataRender : filterRender}
```

<sub>As @jsdeveloper pointed out below, it would be a good idea to make a `renderRow` method to handle this.</sub>

Comment: I have one more question , Could you please ?

Comment: @Jon what's your question?

Comment: Actually , I want to accept input in both lowercase or uppercase or Capitalize . How I can do this .? Please help

Comment: @Jon change the search query to lowercase and the the item to compare to lowercase:

`let keyword =event.target.value.toLowerCase();
let filtered=this.state.data.filter((item)=>{
  return item.companyName.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1
});
`

Comment: Thank You for your message . Actually now I have problem to next button if I search something in search box and click on next button it give me array in console . it not udpating UI on next .

Comment: Please help me out in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55166774/react-search-filter-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I would add to asleepace answer would be that you should create a function to map to a dataitem:

```
getDataItems(data) {
    return data.map((dataItem)=>(
      <Table.Row key={dataItem.id}>
      <Table.Cell>{dataItem.companyName}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{dataItem.primaryPhone}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{dataItem.emailAddress}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{dataItem.venueCode}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{dataItem.account}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{dataItem.openDate}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{dataItem.website}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{dataItem.description}</Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
    ))
}
render() {
  const filteredItems = getDataItems(this.state.filtered)
  const dataItems = getDataItems(this.state.data)
  ...
```

Comment: Please help me out in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55166774/react-search-filter-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 1):

You should add a state prop that handles if the Component is ready to render or you have to render a loader.

This will solve the issue that if your property `this.state.data` ist already populated by your `getDataMethod`.

So you should try adding a inital state proeprty like:

```
class Organization extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      Item : 5,
      skip:0,
      isReady: false,
      data : [],
      filtered:[]
    }
    this.getData=this.getData.bind(this);
    this.btnClick=this.btnClick.bind(this);
    this.prevButton=this.prevButton.bind(this);
  }
```

and you should handle the isReady State in your `getData` like :

```
 getData(){
    const {Item,skip}=this.state;
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8001/parties?filter[limit]=${Item}&&filter[skip]=${skip}`)
    .then(response=>{
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({
        isReady: true,
        data:response.data
      })
    })
  }
```

And add a condition in your `render` method:

```
render() {
    if( !this.state.isReady ){
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    // return your JSX
    return ....
}
```

Comment: Please help me out in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55166774/react-search-filter-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test this to be certain but I expect that that dataRender const is returning a series of rows without a containing parent. The correct way to do this would be to create a `<TableRow />` component that uses the map function inside the render function in your jsx like so:

```
...
<Table.Body>
    {this.state.filtered.length === 0 ? 
    this.state.data.map((dataItem)=>(<TableRow key={dataItem.id} item={dataItem}/>)
    : this.state.filtered}
</Table.Body>
...
```

Comment: Please help me out in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55166774/react-search-filter-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was a really simple solution. I had an object nested within an object, then I tried displaying that object within JSX, rather than a property of that object. This error was showing at the line where that object was set to the state, not where the object was called from the state within JSX.

Object in the state:

```
    test: { status: { id: 1, text: "value" } }
```

JSX (wrong)

```
<div>{this.state.test.status}</div>
```

JSX (right)

```
<div>{this.state.test.status.text}</div>
```